# How to rename the title of the HTML Report generated by pytest-html plug in?

Tags: pytest-html

I am generating html report using `pytest-html` plugin. I'm executing the pytest file by giving `"pytest --html=report.html"` in command line.
So the name and title of the html report generated is report.html. I want to change the title of the generated report.
Please let me know, how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Since v2.1.0, this plugin exposes a [hook](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#pytest_html.hooks.pytest_html_report_title) called before adding the title to the report. You can add this to conftest.py:

```
def pytest_html_report_title(report):
   report.title = 'your title!'
```

This is also explained in the plugin's [User Guide](https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#report-title).

Answer (score 2):

create conftest.py file in the same folder of the test.
this file is used to configure pytest.
put this snippet inside

```
def pytest_html_results_summary(prefix, summary, postfix):
    prefix.extend([html.h1("A GOOD TITLE")])
```

if you need to change the html report file name you can try something like this

```
# @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_configure(config):
    # to remove environment section
    config._metadata = None

    if not os.path.exists('reports'):
        os.makedirs('reports')

    config.option.htmlpath = 'reports/' + datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S") + ".html"
```

my example will put the report.html file in a folder called reports naming with a date instead of a static name

Comment: Thankyou so much. If we add in conftest. py, is it executes before my test run?  If i want to display version number in the title, and i will get version number from one of the test case execution. So if i want to rename the title after test cases execution, what i need to do.

Comment: I want to change name of the html report after my test execution. Is it possible?

Comment: I have one global variable pytest.versionnumber. I will set this variable in one of my test case(ex:Read_version_info). After that, i need to update report name and title.In the report name and title, i need to append this pytest.versionnumber variable. It is giving error(pytest does not have versionnumber variable) when appending this variable to report name,when i tried as given above. Is there anything wrong with global variable declaration. Iam able to use that variable in other functions in the conftest.py file

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the code there is no mean to change only the report's title yet, it is for now hardcoded as

```
html.h1(os.path.basename(self.logfile))
```

So the report title will always be the report file name. I've just pushed a merge request to the project to add a new hook to allow the change of the title without changing the file name, we will see if it is accepted.